# Just another undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'

Tags: c++, gcc, boost, qnx, momentics

At the beginning I must assure You that I've tried almost every solution from similar topics , still they didn't solve my issue.

I'm building  binaries from Boost 1.57 using **MinGW**.

Boost libraries I'm using: *thread* and *system* build without any errors.
I was trying:

> toolset=gcc --target-os=qnxnto and toolset=gcc --target-os=qnx, both didn't work.

I'm including correctly both libraries:

> -lboost_system-mgw48-mt-d-1_57 -lboost_thread-mgw48-mt-d-1_57

after using:

> `#define BOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED`

I got rid of `boost::system::generic_category()` error, still I can't get rid of:

> boost::system::system_category()

I'm working in **QNX Momentics**.
I'm totally out of ideas, I'm really looking forward for any help I can get.

Comment: Where on the compiler command line are these linker options that you show? Put them behind your sources/objects

Comment: They are behind source files.